# knockout.js using a ko.observable via a selected value in a ko.computed statement

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to achieve the following with knockout with some difficulty:

1. Bind a select form element ... this works
2. Display the selected option via a ko.observable ... this works
3. Use the ko.observable from #2 inside a ko.computed variable... I cant figure this out.

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W2ABG/) of my attempt so far. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computed observables are evaluated immediately.  When you create your `viewModel` variable in an object literal like in your example, it can't be used yet in your computed observable.

A couple choices.  Write it like:

```
var viewModel = {
    optionValues: [10, 20, 30],
    selectedOptionValue: ko.observable()
};

viewModel.multipledValue = ko.computed(function(){
    return this.selectedOptionValue() * 3;
}, viewModel);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);​
```

or

```
var ViewModel = function() {
   this.optionValues = [10, 20, 30];
   this.selectedOptionValue = ko.observable();
   this.multipledValue = ko.computed(function(){
        return this.selectedOptionValue() * 3;
   }, this);

};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Also, `selectedOptionValue` is an observable, so you would read its value by calling it as a function with no arguments like:  `this.selectedOptionValue()`